# How to set <C+k> as vim leader key?

Tags: leader

I've tried

```
let mapleader="<C+k>"
```

or

```
let mapleader="\<C+k>"
```

But it seems that both of them can't work.

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
let mapleader="\<C-k>"
```

It works as expected.

Comment: Lol @filbranden, I just saw this in review as Low-quality because of length :{ nothing to  worry about, obviously, just thought it was funny

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  It struck me as short, didn't expect it would be flagged as possible Low-Quality, but I thought answering was right (better than comment) and not much point in saying more than this, since the OP was already super close to the answer... Anyways, thanks for not flagging it as spam! 

Comment: Np; robots only get you so far. It’s pretty much what id have written, at any rate

Answer (score 2):

filbranden is right. Another solution would be:

```
let mapleader="^K"
```

`^K` is inserted by typing `<C-V><C-K>`.
A key typed after `<C-V>` will be inserted literally. It's very useful. See `:h i_CTRL-V` for more information.